# How to add value to dynamic input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, input

I am Creating one input box dynamically using **javascript**

Below is the Code:

```
var addtxt = document.createElement("input");
addtxt.type = "text";
addtxt.name = "admissionno" ;
addtxt.id = "admissionno" ;
```

If i add  value in static way it will take using `addtxt.value="11";`
But am adding like this dynamically

```
addtxt.value=result.studentlist[j].admissionno
```

it will not work.please give me the idea its helpful for me.

Comment: Is there a value in `result.studentlist[j].admissionno`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("admissionno").value = (result.studentlist[j].admissionno);
```

Comment: @user2996174 Good to hear. Would be great if you accept this as answer :-)